# Searching array with an If Statement ASP

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic

I have this function searching if a value exist through an array. Here's my function:

```
Function in_array(iCountryID, iCountryArray)
in_array = False
For i=0 To Ubound(iCountryArray)
    If iCountryArray(i) = iCountryID Then
        in_array = True
        Exit Function      
     End If
 Next
 End Function

 ThisCountry = iCountryID
 CountryArray = Array(99,115,218,305)
 If in_array(ThisCountry, CountryArray) Then 
     Response.Write ThisCountry & " is in the array"
 Else 
     Response.Write ThisCountry & " is not in the array"
 End If
```

This works fine. My issue is that the values inside my array (99,115,218,305) are dynamic. I have a variable that creates that value through a query.

iCountryArray is my variable that stores the values 99,115,218,305. So instead of manually entering those values to my array, I need to add them dymanically.

This doesn't work:

```
CountryArray = Array(" & iCountryArray & ")
```

Comment: Is this Visual Basic?

Comment: yes. trying to put this on an Classic ASP web application

Comment: What exactly is `iCountryArray`? Is it a string?

Comment: @melpomene The appearance of `response.write` and the lack of types in the function declares a pretty big hints that we are in classic ASP. And iCountryArray is an array of numbers.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I have no idea what ASP is. I was just looking for better tags. :-)

Comment: Oh ok. Well the VBScript and asp-classic are appropriate. Arrays is borderline and if-statement is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If your iCountryArray has the country numbers concatenated into it then you can use the `Split()` function to make an array. This means you can have as many country numbers as you need. Note though that the string will split to a string array and you want a numeric test so we wrap in `cLng()` function within the function:

```
Function in_array(iCountryID, iCountryArray)
  in_array = False
  For i=0 To Ubound(iCountryArray)
     If cLng(iCountryArray(i)) = iCountryID Then ' use cLng to convert to number type
        in_array = True
        Exit Function      
     End If
  Next
End Function

ThisCountry = iCountryID
CountryArray = split(sCountryList, ",") ' assuming sCountryList is like "12,33,55,3,99" etc
If in_array(ThisCountry, CountryArray) Then 
     Response.Write ThisCountry & " is in the array"
Else 
     Response.Write ThisCountry & " is not in the array"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Got carried away a little by an alternative use case, to provide a more direct answer here a method in which your string of countrycodes stays a string and we simply look if the substring is in that string.
To ensure the whole substring is there I use demimiters (the ones inside your string) to envelop the search and searched string.

```
CountryCodes = "99,115,218,305"
ThisCountry = "99"

Function Envelop(string)
  Envelop = "," & string & ","
End Function

Function InString(substring, string)
  Instring = (Instr(Envelop(string), Envelop(substring)) > 0)
End Function


If InString(ThisCountry, CountryCodes) Then 
  Wscript.Echo ThisCountry & " is in the string"
Else 
  Wscript.Echo ThisCountry & " is not in the string"
End If
```

NB Not part of the answer but since I do all of my scripts also in Ruby here the Ruby version.
In Ruby the check and printing could be a oneliner

```
country_codes = "99,115,218,305"
this_country  = "99"

puts "#{this_country} is " + (",#{country_codes},"[",#{this_country},"] ? "" : "not") + " in the string"
```

OR using a regular expression

```
puts "#{this_country} is #{(country_codes.match(/\b#{this_country}\b/) ? "" : "not")} in the string"
```

Some explenation: in a string enclosed with `""` `#{}` inserts the code within, it is a powerful way of concatenating.
`.match(/\b#{this_country}\b/)` uses a regular expresion to match the string enclosed in `//`, in this case the variable `this_country`

Don't know if it is possible or your use case but look at the following code, hope it is usefull..

You could use a Dictionary of Country codes and names and use it like this..

```
Set Countries = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
With Countries
  .Add "99", "Some Country"
  .Add "115", "Some other Country"
  .Add "218", "Still Some Country"
  .Add "305", "Another Country"
End With

Sub ShowCountry(code)
  code = Cstr(code)
  For Each country in Countries
    If Countries.Item(code) > "" Then
      Wscript.Echo Countries.Item(code)
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Next
  Wscript.Echo "Country with code " & code & " doesn't exist"
End Sub

ShowCountry 115 'Some other Country'
ShowCountry 9 'Country with code 9 doesn't exist'
```

Again here the Ruby version

```
Countries = {99 => "Some Country", 115 => "Some other Country", 218 => "Still Some Country", 305 => "Another Country"}

def show_country code
  puts Countries[code] || "Country with code #{code} doesn't exist"
end

show_country 115 # Some other Country
show_country 9 #Country with code 9 doesn't exist
```

Comment: How is this even remotely dynamic?

Comment: You'r right, got carried away in another use case, added an answer more to the point